# $SSH_CONNECTION Does not display the IP addresses or port port numbers of ssh cnnections

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, environment-variables, openssh

`echo $SSH_CONNECTION` does not display anything on the SSH server. I use my laptop to connect to my server using a key-less SSH setup. After SSHing to my server, if I run `echo $SSH_CONNECTION` in a terminal on the server from the machine itself I'm supposed to see the IP address and port numbers of my remote and local server client, however nothing is displayed. I am wondering if anyone can guide me in fixing this issue?

I have Ubuntu 16.04 running on both machines.

Comment: Perhaps you can [edit] to be clearer here, but I think that sounds normal if you're saying that `SSH_CONNECTION` is only set from within the SSH session. If that's not what you're saying then [edit] to break it down into what you see, where, and what you expected.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/608956/get-current-ssh-sessions-originating-ip-without-being-superuser Please refer to this link. this will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SSH_CONNECTION` environment variable will be set in the SSH session. It will not be set for any other process on the SSH server than for those started from the SSH connection from the client.

If you are logged in directly on the SSH server (on the physical machine, not through SSH), and type `echo $SSH_CONNECTION`, then I'm expecting that to output nothing.

So, logging in with SSH and then printing the value of `$SSH_CONNECTION` ought to look something like

```
[client] $ ssh username@server.example.com

[server] $ echo "$SSH_CONNECTION"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx nnnnn yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy 22
```

Where `x` is your client's IP address, `n` is the port used on the client, and `y` is the server's IP address.

Comment: Do u know how can I add this $SSH_CONNECTION to my Rsyslog? I've added it to a local log, but this information doesn't show on logs, I'm receiving something like this ` root: root@ [8399]: clear [0]`

Comment: @MuriloMelo This depends on who/what is doing the logging. Without `SSH_CONNECTION` in that process' environment, I'd expect it to expand to an empty string.